# Unable to find logFiles to see which opens/closes my X11 in Mac

Tags: macos, x11

My X11 opens and closes repeatedly. I can see only the following at my Dock

```
Application not responding
```

**How can you find logFiles which tell me the application that opens/closes X11 continuously?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no log that keeps track which application started/stopped X11. And at least on my machine, X11 is also started always by the launchd process (with X11 running, type "ps xa -O ppid | grep X11" in a terminal to see the process ID of the parent (2nd column)).

For me, X11 starts when I use ssh and also when I start any X11 application (e.g. xterm). Maybe you can just look at what other applications are running at the time X11 starts.

In addition, you mentioned "Application not responding" which I assume relates to X11 itself. Hence it is more likely that the X11 server simply crashed (or is stuck somehow) instead of some other application stopping it. In this case you maybe find some infos in your **Library/Logs/CrashReporter** directory (both your Library and the system Library).

Comment: @dseifert: Thank you for the log-file directory! I will keep an eye on it.